# Delete everything starting from "\\" and ending at the white space

Tags: shell

I have a text file contains:

```
台北市\\tai2bei3shi4 警察局\\jing3cha2ju2.
```

I want to delete everything starting from `\\` and ending at the white space. The result looks like this:

```
台北市 警察局
```

How can I do it? Is there a one line command?

Comment: You can use search and replace utility. Search the pattern and replace it with a white space.

Comment: If you delete everything starting from \\ and ending at the white space you will get `台北市警察局\\jing3cha2ju2.`  not `台北市 警察局`

Answer (score 1):

This works using [GNU sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/):

```
sed 's/\\[^ ]*//g' <textfile>
```

Sed's replacement works as follows: `s/regexp/replacement/`

- The `regexp` part is `\\[^ ]*`, which means 'find a `\` and any non-whitespace character following it'
- The `replacement` is empty because we want to replace the matched `regexp` part with nothing
- `g` means that the replacement should be performed as many times possible on each line

Answer (score 0):

If you delete everything starting from \\ and ending at the white space you will get

`台北市警察局\\jing3cha2ju2.`

not

`台北市 警察局`

But if you want to get `台北市 警察局` :

```
sed -r 's/\\\\[^ ]+( |\.)//g' file.txt
```

yields the following output:

```
台北市警察局
```

You can send the output to a second file by adding `> file2.txt`

`\\\\`   you have to scape both characters, that's why there are four of them

`[^ ]+`  a series of characters not including a space

`( |\.)` a space or a dot ( dot must be scaped )

`-r`  so you don't have to scape square brackets or parenthesis

Answer (score 0):

a sed line based on your input:

```
sed 's/[0-9a-zA-Z.\\\\]*//g' file
```

**test**

```
kent$  echo "台北市\\tai2bei3shi4 警察局\\jing3cha2ju2."|sed 's/[0-9a-zA-Z.\\\\]*//g'
台北市  警察局
```